# Mule null property values

Tags: mule

Mule 3.4.1 puts out a warning when a null value is assigned to a flow variable.

```
WARN setProperty(key, value) called with null value; removing key: _enricher.text;     please report the following stack trace to dev@mule.codehaus.org
java.lang.Throwable
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.setProperty(DefaultMuleMessage.java:457)
...etc.
```

However, sometimes null is what is desired.  Other than monkeying with specific loggers, is there any way to avoid this?  For example, in the following the descriptive text may be null.  I don't want to have to pass empty strings all over the place if I can avoid it.

```
<enricher>
    <flow-ref name="myFlow"/>
    <enrich target="#[variable:status]" source="#[message.payload.STATUS]"/>
    <enrich target="#[variable:descriptiveText]" source="#[message.payload.?TEXT]"/>
</enricher>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set log4j's level for `org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage` to `ERROR`.

Comment: Yes.  I was hoping to avoid changing logger values.  I'm assuming from your response that isn't possible?

Comment: Correct. Before posting my answer, I checked if the source code shown any way to disable this null check, but the answer is no. You can see for yourself: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.0/core/src/main/java/org/mule/DefaultMuleMessage.java#L457